# wrap multiple <p> in a div with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

In the following markup there are two `<p>` tags. How can I wrap both of them in a single div using jQuery?

```
<div class="box">
    <ul>
        <li>1</li>
        <li>1</li>
    </ul>
    <p>paragraph 1</p>
    <p>paragraph 2</p>
</div>
```

Desired output should be:

```
<div class="wrap">
    <p>paragraph 1</p>
    <p>paragraph 2</p>
</div>
```

I have been trying jQuery function .wrap, but failed to do so. I could only try following but it would wrap both `<p>` in separate `<div>`:

```
$( "p" ).wrap( "<div class='wrap'></div>" );
```

**JSFiddle:**
http://jsfiddle.net/avfr8fpe/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use [wrapAll](http://api.jquery.com/wrapAll/):

```
$( "p" ).wrapAll( "<div class='wrap'></div>" );
```

[Updated jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/206gv94o/)

Comment: if it known which elements are to be wraped specifically, then the selector can be fine tuned : http://jsfiddle.net/206gv94o/1/